# AWS sam local possible to acces a local webpage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam-cli

Is it possible to access the aws api gateway in aws SAM local with a webpage?
at the moment I have everything running local (amazon DynamoDB, (aws lambda, aws api gateway with aws sam local)) but I can't access the api's with a ajax call because I have no rights is there an option to give it rights or disable the rights so I can test my real ajax calls?

update1:
solved the CORS prob with an addon for chrome that enables it all the time for itself but now i can see my output in the previeuw in the developer options of chrome (F12) but i still get a 502 bad gateway, any idea why this is?

update2:
okay solved that problem to, but now i want to do a post from my webpage true my api gateway true my lambda to my DynamoDB i know i can use the event in the lambda **exports.post = (event, context, callback)** but it is just plain empty in the body so i cannot get anything in it so i can't get anything out of it.
the curl statement i use:
**curl -d '{"id": 8}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/resource**
i can just see:
**body: '\'{id:',**
as you can see no 8 in it to use.
anybody got any answer or work around?

many thanks
Liam

Comment: What do you mean you have no rights? Did you enable CORS? Does your Lambda output the right CORS headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the problem was that i had:
contentType: 
"application/json; charset=utf-8",
and
dataType: "json",
in my ajax call removed those and everything works fine.